# The meaning of ～のみ

Tags: grammar

What is the meaning/significance of `～のみ`? Does it have anything to do with [`身`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%BF&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&index=118663400000&pagenum=1) or [`見`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%BF&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&index=118663300000&pagenum=1)?

Some example sentences:

> - しかし、予算の制限のため、差し当たり実験機のみを製造することになった。
>     But budget restrictions have allowed them to make only prototypes for the time being.
> - そして、内で行われる茶の湯の作法のみが美しく見え、そこに宇宙空間や禅の思想までもが表現されたもの。
>     In that context, the tea ceremony becomes the focus of beauty, while ideas of space and Zen are also communicated.
> - 両商品とも、コンビニのみで販売されている。
>     Both products are sold only at convenience stores.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means "only". You can think of it as the written version of だけ.

のみ can replace だけ except for these cases:

> - i-adjectives: 高い{だけ・*のみ}
> - na-adjectives: 静かな{だけ・*のみ}
> - quantifiers: 一つ{だけ・*のみ}
>
> <sub>* denoting unacceptability</sub>

Also case particles may appear before/after のみ with virtually no difference in meaning except for で.

- Xでのみ, Y - Only using X, Y.
- Xのみで, Y - Using "Only X", Y.

Comment: d'oh! I was parsing the `み` separate to the `の`. Should've looked it up separately. Thanks!

Comment: more than a written version, a keigo version of だけ would be a better fit.

Comment: Incidentally, many believe that it is etymologically の身, but it's an indivisible particle with its own idiomatic meaning at this point (as Flaw explains).

Comment: @oldergod What do you mean by keigo version of だけ? It sounds senseless to me.

Comment: 「のみ」is not an honorific or keigo... it's just one of 副助詞 in literary style...

Comment: @sawa Because it is used as well in speaking language. In strong keigo's environment like work, department store etc.

Comment: @oldergod I don't understand what you are writing.

Comment: @oldergod, what kind of keigo would this be? Sonkeigo, kenjougo or teineigo? I think 'formal' might be more precise than 'written'. Formal language is used in spoken language all the time.

Comment: I used to get coffee at the same shop every day and used to ask for "ミルクだけ。" when asked whether I wanted milk and sugar, the lady behind the counter always used to confirm, "ミルクのみ？". Thinking that I had missed something in understanding the difference, I started to say, "ミルクのみ。" to which she replied, "ミルクだけ？"...